# Modifying wso2 api manager to work only on HTTP port

Tags: wso2-api-manager

In existing wso2 api manager the carbon is listening at HTTPS port and publisher,store are listening at HTTP port. 
But I need to make all the components of the wso2 api manager to work on the HTTP port 8080. 
What changes are need to be done in existing wso2 api manager?

Comment: I think this is not a topic for stackoverflow.com It would be better to ask your question at Serverfault.com or at Superuser

Answer (score 0):

You can change the default  ports-9443,9763 in repository/conf/tomcat/catalina-server.xml and the default  ports-8280,8243
repository/conf/axis2/axis2.xml

Comment: I need to deploy whole application on 8080 port. Since I need to deploy it on the PCF(pivotal cloud foundry), the PCF can only call the 8080 port of the application.I don't want the HTTPS in picture. So what changes are need to be done for this change?